# Print complete list

Tags: list

I am trying to print a list but I get a partial list when calling

```
(message "%S" mylist)

("richad" "richda" "ricahd" "ricadh" "ricdha" "ricdah" "rihcad"
 "rihcda" "rihacd" "rihadc" "rihdca" "rihdac" ...)
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate this issue. Please add the following two pieces of information to your question: where the partial list goes (you say you "get" it, how do you "get" it?), and what is the complete list?

Comment: Do note in addition that you may want to use `%s` instead of `%S` (but obviously I am not sure what you are trying to do so I could be wrong). See the documentation for the `format` function for details.

Answer (score 1):

[This is the rare case where this OP's question might be more widely interesting. It is about Emacs. And IMO, it should not have been downvoted. Going back to ignore mode afterwards.]

Do

```el
(setq eval-expression-print-length nil)     ;; default is 12
(setq eval-expression-print-level nil)      ;; default is 4
```

That ensures that on evaluation, lists are printed in their entirety, no matter how long or deep they are.